# Dynamic image for download in jsp page as per file availability

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have a download link in google table:

```
'<a href="<%= FilePath%>" height="20" width="20" download/><img src="/img/download.png" alt=" Image " title="Click to download" height="20" width="20" /></a>',
```

where FilePath can be local or on some server. And on the basis of availability of the file, i have to change the image(download.png) either downloadable or not available.

Can anyone help on this?

I am new to JSP and servlets so please elaborate the solution.

Comment: How do you know if the file is available or not? Do you have a flag that is either true or false that you can test?

Comment: That is what is required. The check on file!
After this i guess, we can put some condition to have the image accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution that will determine if a resource is available to download or not is to open a connection to that resource and check the response code. The response can tell you if the connection was made successfully or not. We can assume that if the connection was made successfully then the file is available to download. A successful connection sends a response code of 200. We can assume that any other response code means that the connection was not successful.

To do this we can create a servlet called **CheckResponseStatus** like so:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {             
    String remoteImageUrl = request.getParameter("remoteImageUrl");         
    String imageUrl = "http://localhost:8000/WEBAPP/images/download.png";

    URL url = new URL(remoteImageUrl);
    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    int statusCode = http.getResponseCode();

    if (statusCode != 200) {
        imageUrl = "http://localhost:8000/WEBAPP/images/notAvailable.png";       
    }

    response.getWriter().write(imageUrl);        
}
```

We pass the URL of the resource as a query string parameter and retrieve it using the `request.getParameter("remoteImageUrl")`. We then open a connection to the resource `url.openConnection()` and retrieve the response code `http.getResponseCode()`.

Now that we have the response code we test it to determine if we have connected successfully to the resource `if (statusCode != 200)`. If so, we return the URL of the download image otherwise the URL of the not available image.

So this servlet will return either `http://localhost:8000/WEBAPP/images/download.png`, if the resource is available, or `http://localhost:8000/WEBAPP/images/notavailable.png`, if not available, as a string of text which we can insert into an `<img src="">` tag.

In the JSP we need to pass the URL of the resource to the servlet.

```
 <%
     pageContext.setAttribute("FilePath1", "http://www.google.com/humans.txt");
     pageContext.setAttribute("FilePath2", "http://www.example.com/filedoesnotexist.doc");
 %>

 <a href="${FilePath1}">
      <img src="<jsp:include page="CheckResponseStatus?remoteImageUrl=${FilePath1}"/>"/>
 </a>
 <a href="${FilePath2}">
      <img src="<jsp:include page="CheckResponseStatus?remoteImageUrl=${FilePath2}"/>"/>
 </a>
```

In this example I have hard coded the URL and added them to the pageContext as attributes. I have done it this way so we can use Expression Language rather then scriptlets (scriptlets are not recommended).

I use the standard action `<jsp:include>` to call the servlet. This action issues a call to the servlet and whatever the response is from the servlet it is includes in the translated JSP page. The name of the resource is attached as a query string parameter to the call to the servlet `${FilePath1}`. This query string is retrieved by the servlet using `request.getParameter("remoteImageUrl")`.

This line of code allows us to dynamically test the connection status of any file we pass as a parameter to the CheckResponseStatus servlet.

This is just a proof of concept and can be improved substantial. I have included just the bare minimum required to get it to work. You will need to make it more robust, handle exception and other response codes.

I hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: perfect answer for me..with little changes as per the requirements, the code is working. Thanks Alex